# Get dimension of a path in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, bounding-box

I need to get the dimension on the screen of a <path> in a SVG from JavaScript.

I do not have any "transformation" or "scaling" (transform, scale) on my SVG.
The only thing changed is the viewBox, which will change the size of all the elements in the SVG.

I have been using myPath.getBBox(), the width returned stays the same even though I change my viewBox.

So I'm wondering what is the relation with this viewBox and size of a path. Maybe there is a function to compute the width?

Comment: I think you need to be slightly more precise: you want the _bounding box dimensions_, right? And do you want these in SVG coordinates or screen coordinates?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can call `getBoundingClientRect()` method on your path to get dimensions. It will return a `ClientRect` object:

```
var w = myPath.getBoundingClientRect().width;
var h = myPath.getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

There is also a `getScreenCTM()` method, which returns the transformation matrix in the current screen pixels of the element it was called on.
the spec [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getScreenCTM):

> [getScreenCTM()] Returns the transformation matrix from current user units (i.e., after application of the ‘transform’ attribute, if any) to the parent user agent's notice of a "pixel". [...] Note that null is returned if this element is not hooked into the document tree.

Answer (score 2):

First off all, keep in mind that `path` cannot have a width. Its a set of coords. The browser uses that info along with the drawing method to connect the coords and create a visible shape.

Secondly, the bounding box is a snapshot of when the SVG was rendered. That is why you don't get the updated width on resize.

A workaround I guess would be to get the width of the conatiner element to the SVG (`div` or something else).

Maybe some of the [libraries](http://www.farinspace.com/top-svg-javascript-libraries-worth-looking-at/) may provide some utility method to figure this out.