# Problems getting the length of a percentage based SVG path in JS

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I need to have a full screen SVG path that I draw in, but it needs to be percentage based for all devices, however when I measure the path length in JS it's just returning `400` due to the path definition being as follows:

```
<path id="path" d="M 0,0 0,100 100,100 100,0 0,0"></path>
```

I need to measure the total length of the path so I can use dash-array and dash-offset to draw it in in one smooth transition.

Here's a codepen with an example mocked up: https://codepen.io/jaybox325/pen/vjBgMe?editors=1111

Is it even possible to measure this because it's doesn't technically have an absolute length.

I have got a fallback version made using pseudo elements, but I'd like to use an SVG if possible!

Thanks!

Comment: Explain what you want the path to look like rather than your problems with lengths. I suspect this is an X Y problem.

Comment: I suspect you just want a viewBox and then you can use absolute paths.

Comment: Thanks @raul.vila! I struggled for the terminology to search with and hadn't come across the getBoundingClientRect function before.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't worry, marking as duplicate has the intention to provide and answer and link your question with that answer for future users which may find your question instead of the original.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to raul.vila in the comments, I managed to use the `getBoundingClientRect()` function to get the width and height of the rectangle and use these lengths to animate the path perfectly.

More details here: [Get dimension of a path in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032403/get-dimension-of-a-path-in-svg)